# Automatically convert properties file in Java source

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, properties, eclipse-neon

I've a configuration file `config.properties` that I use to store all the needed configurations for my application. I also use a Java class `ApplicationConfig` loaded by spring, that essentially maps each property to Java getters.

**config.properties**

```
main.path=C:\\
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
public class ApplicationConfig {
    private static transient Properties config;

    public ApplicationConfig(Properties config) {
        ApplicationConfig.config = config;
    }

    public static String getMainPath() {
        return config.getProperty("main.path");
    }
}
```

Each and every time I change the properties file I've to rework my Java class. Since it's a simple transformation that can be easily done programmatically, is there a way to instruct Eclipse that every time I save the properties file (or on build) the java file gets reworked automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Probably eclipse has some sort of **code** generation support that allows you to do that, but I recommend: do **not** make yourself dependent on your IDE!

What happens when you decide to switch to another IDE? Then all the time you invested here would be lost!

And beyond that: you are talking about a **core** element of your product. Shouldn't that *core* be built **automatically**; by some *build tool*?

Thus: I would rather look into command line tools to do that.

Worst case: write a script in your favorite language; or even in Java that  works like this:

- It reads some **template** description of your properties file, containing entries like `property-name: main.path`, `property-type: String`, `property-getter: getMainPath`, `property-default: C:\\bla`
- Now that **tool** generates the required source code, **plus** the properties file itself.

In short: you should balance "easy to implement" versus "easy to maintain over time". If you are "serious" about your product, you will find sooner or later (rather: sooner) that **any** build step that requires **manual** intervention (like: firing up your IDE to push a button) will slow you down; and dramatically impact your ability to *automate* your deployment process. And that is something that nobody should be going for lighthearted in 2017.

Of course: the **less** own proprietary code you write to implement this requirement, the better. But then look for "command line" solutions; not something that requires an IDE to be up and running to do the processing!

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). It can generate getters/setter with a simple annotation and much, much more. It integrates with Eclipse (and IDEA) via a plugin and can be used with most build tools in use today.